# Pandas time conversion not consistent?

Tags: pandas, timestamp

I tried to convert a timestamp to a datetime object in a dataframe using the apply method, however, when I convert the datetime object back to timestamp, it is a different timestamp. Has anyone encountered this issue and how to resolve this?

As above

```
original_ts = 1564560384
a = pd.DataFrame({"ts": [original_ts]})
a["time"] = a["ts"].apply(lambda x: 
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
a["time"].iloc[0].timestamp()
# outputs 1564545984.0
```

I expected the output to be the same as the original_ts but it is not

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that timezone is None:

```
import datetime
original_ts = 1564560384
a = pd.DataFrame({"ts": [original_ts]})
a["time"] = a["ts"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x, tz=None))
a["time"].iloc[0].timestamp() # 1564560384.0
```